# How to put JSON path into the API route

Tags: android, sql, json, flutter, api

I have this api call ..so it gets the api from my api page which links to the backend. But how may I link it to my json file? The first image is current one..wanna change it to the second image where I set the api to the json path.

Current

[image: [Current](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fB9kQ.png)]

What I want

[image]

```
response =
            await rootBundle.loadString('assets/images/profile/wordjson.json');
```

tried it like this to replace the api with the json i had but no use..the application does not display it.
Also this is the json i have

```
{
    "Data": [
        {
            "plantUniqueId": "215dce885e",
            "hpfPlantId": 7,
            "hpfScientificName": "Ctenitis fijiensis (Hooker) Copeland (syn. Ctenitis squamigera uct. Copel.)",
            "hpfLocalName": "Ctenitis fijiensis (Hooker) Copeland (syn. Ctenitis squamigera uct. Copel.)",
            "hpfPlantImgUrl": "images/plants/image_1643057089.5149/101.jpg",
            "hpfBriefDescriptionEng": "[Per jumper siqeleti ni katakata]",
            "hpfBriefDescriptionFj": "1",
            "hpfDistributionEng": "jaba",
            "hpfDistributionFj": "n",
            "hpfMedicalUseFijiEng": "vinivo lekaleka yaco toka ga e dibi, dau tokari vata kei na isuluira;",
            "hpfMedicalUseFijiFj": "r kote 2;",
            "hpfMedicalUseOtherEng": "[Per jumpern siqeleti ni katakata]",
            "hpfMedicalUseOtherFj": "[Per jumper siqeleti ni katakata]",
            "hpfPropertiesInterestEng": "[Per jumper siqeleti ni katakata]",
            "hpfPropertiesInterestFj": "[Per jumper siqeleti ni katakata]",
            "hpfSpecialNoteEng": "[Per jumper siqeleti ni katakata]",
            "hpfSpecialNoteFj": "[Per jumper siqeleti ni katakata]",
            "plantFamily": "[Per jumper siqeleti ni katakata]"
        }
       
    ]
}
```

And this was the backend table
[hia](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1bgSn.png)

Answer (score 0):

decode it:

```js
Map<String, dynamic> jsonData = jsonDecode(jsonString);
```

Comment: already decoded it with this ```plantDetailsJson = json.decode(response) plantDetailsJson = json.decode(response);
      plant = Plant.fromJson(plantDetailsJson['plant'], _lang)```..is it correct?

Comment: plant = Plant.fromJson(plantDetailsJson['plant'])